# map field types when ingesting twitter json to elastic search with python

Tags: json, python-3.x, curl, elasticsearch, twitter

I'm loading JSON objects from the twitter API to an elastic search instance using a python script.

A list contains tweets as JSON objects, which are parsed to elastic search.

```
import elasticsearch
import json
import requests

tweet_list = request(get_tweets_via_request)
for tweet in tweet_list:
    es.index(index="twitter",doc_type="tweet",body=tweet)
```

Before loading in elastic search, I want to map the `created_at` field as  `string` instead of `date`. If I run the python script without configuring any mapping, ES interprets the `created_at` field as `string`.

`{"created_at":{"type":"string"}`

I'm trying to apply some mappings before running the python script using a curl command with the mappings (with carrige returns/spaces removed) inline:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/twitter -d {"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":1}},"mappings":{"tweet":{"properties":{"created_at":{"format":"EEEMMMddHH:mm:ssZYYYY","type":"date"}}}}}
```

and the resulting error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse source for create index"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse source for create index","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unrecognized token 'EEEMMMddHH': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@14b6e4; line: 1, column: 99]"}},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the following mapping](https://github.com/humangeo/some-elasticsearch-mappings/blob/master/twitter-elasticsearch-mapping) in order to create the index before indexing tweets.

As you can see the `created_at` field is declared as date with a specific date format matching what comes in the Twitter feed.

```
PUT /twitter
{
  "settings" : {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards" : 1
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tweet": {
        "properties": {
            "created_at": {
                "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY",
                "type": "date"
            },
            ...
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Val, thanks - still trying to get it to work. have tried via python and via curl commands, but can't get the mappings to register.

when I ping ES using curl I get a response but whenever I try to put mappings I get `could not resolve host` type errors

Comment: Can you show the curl request you're trying to send?

Comment: sure, 
`curl -X PUT localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping?ignore_conflicts=true -d \ {...`

Comment: Please update your question with what you're doing and the error you're getting.

Comment: hi Val, apologies for the delayed response. I've tried the updated mappings and I'm still getting the same error, whether I apply to an existing index or a non-existent one.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact command you're running and the exact error you get?

Comment: updated to reflect the new `mappings.json` file and the exact error returned when I run the curl command in the shell.

Comment: Can you try `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/twitter -d '{...your inline json...}'`?

Comment: Your inline JSON is not valid JSON apparently. Are you 100% certain that what you've pasted in your question above is exactly what you're running? It works well for me

Comment: I tried it without the `'` marks around the curly braces, this time a shorter error (updated above)

Comment: You need the single quotes around the curly braces... not sure why it fails for you

Comment: could it be because I've removed the carriage returns/indents? the reason I did this is because I can't paste the entire command into the cmd shell without it executing as separate commands at each carriage return